# Connect to SQL with Azure.entity without DbContext

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET back-end with Entity Framework connecting to an Azure database DSL Server with azure.entity as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-connect-msi-azure-database

I want to write a little Azure job (console application) for a cron operations without entities. But I can connect to the database.

1. I use the connection string like the back-end

   ```
   Server=tcp:mydatabase.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
   ```
2. On my web app azure which receives the job, I set the group permitted on SQL Server like owner.
3. On my web app azure which receives the job, I set the "Identity/managed identity" to true
4. With nuget, I have installed `Azure.Identity` in my job application.
5. For opening the connection, I'm using

   ```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr);
   ```

   But when I try to connect in the job, I get an message

   > Error: Login failed for user ''

I can't use a user login because there wasn't one defined when installing SQL Server.

How can I simply connect to my database?